# Passing variables to MS Forms IFRAME

Tags: iframe, microsoft-forms, ms-forms

I have a MSForms IFRAME like below to which i want to pass variables:

```
<iframe width="640px" height= "480px" src= "https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=WnOMPGahs0mNAXXXXXXLalRLguiTSkoG369UQThGNUlVRjFSWUYyQlpWOTAyVEVUQUNJNyQlQCN0PWcu&embed=true" frameborder= "0" marginwidth= "0" marginheight= "0" style= "border: none; max-width:100%; max-height:100vh" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

I want to dynamically pass variables to the IFRAME to prepopulate certain MS Form fields.

Any hints on how to achieve this. My research was not successfull, however I could find a way for MS Forms Pro but not for MS Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a veriable in iframe with javascript, load below script onLoad i mean on page load the value should be loaded. check it in browser console if you need to be sure.

```
var yourVeriable = "veriableValue";
document.querySelector(".passaclasstoiframe").setAttribute("customattr", yourVeriable);
```

if you have jquery, its much easy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var yourVeriable = "veriableValue";
  $('.passaclasstoiframe').attr("customattr", yourVeriable);
  //but for this, you have to put customattr="" in your iframe.
  //<iframe width="640px" height= "480px" src= "src" customattr=""></iframe>
})
```

if you are doing this with C# asp.net, i will recommend you to use javascript to put a veriable into the iframe.

Comment: the question is how to pass vAriables to ms forms, not to an IFRAME in general.